# I want to be able to drag items anywhere in the group box for the Qualtrics "Pick, Group, Rank" question

Tags: javascript, drag-and-drop, qualtrics

I am using a Pick, group, rank question in qualtrics. I want to be able to select items from a long list and drag them into the group box (I am only using one group box). The trouble is that the item list is long, and regardless of how big the group box appears to be, you have to scroll back up to the top of the top of the page to drop items from the bottom of the list at the top of the group box.

I'd like to adjust my code so that I can drag items from the bottom of the list, for example, anywhere in the group box.

I am currently using the following html question code:

```
<span style="color:#000000;"><u><strong>Select audit evidence to include:</strong></u></span>&nbsp;

<style>
.Skin .PGR .DragAndDrop td.groupsContainerTd div > div {
border: 1px solid;
border-collapse: collapse;
min-height: 20px;
height: 2100px;
}
</style>
```